# First launch take long time (ClassLoader referenced unknown path)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After updating my **Android studio** to 2.0 and **gradle** to 2.0.0 and **SDK-Platform** to 23.0.3 When I want to launch application it take too much time (about 2-3 second) and following warning appears in Android Monitor :

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/net.hadifar.test-1/lib/arm
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/net.hadifar.test-1/lib/arm
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.439ms
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.808ms
```

But second time I launch application it's run as usual. Can any body knows what's the issue ?

Comment: I think `instant-run`  in enabled.. which always taken more time at first run...

Comment: Yes ! Thanks. I disable instant run and issue fixed. for disable instant run go to Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.

Comment: what does it means? (what if i'm setting checked and what if i'm setting unchecked?)

Comment: @Kuriel see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37512413/1462770

Answer (score 10):

In version 2.0 a new feature was added [instant-run](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#instant-run).

To enable this feature tool adds a lots of meta information, so the first build and upload takes more time.

**Be aware** about

- setting minSdkVersion 15 or higher to get any profit;
- Instant Run [does not currently work with Jack](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html) (to support java 8) and will be disabled while using the new toolchain;
- you may still encounter some [glitches and bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954746/emulator-disconnect-frequently-and-android-studio-stuck-how-to-fix-it/37049850#37049850);

Here we can write (or vote) [issues](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=instant-run&sort=priority&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened) (report to make the better tool).

Comment: I have also experienced this issue and in my case the first run time improves significaltly using Instant Run if I set the `minSdkVersion` to `21` as stated here: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/building-studio.html#instant-run

Comment: @antonio, are you serious? How many percent of devices can install your application?

Comment: @CoolMind, maybe I have misexplained it, I mean setting it to 21 only during the development process and as a workaround until the issue is solved

Comment: @antonio, I have just checked it, nothing had changed after upgrading to 21 version. Still very slow first run.

Comment: @CoolMind There are too many variables, only profiling in your concrete case can show improvements, if any, even with some projects it doesn't work at all. Check [limitations](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#ir-limitations).

Answer (score 3):

There is a strange behaviour in newly released `A.S 2.0` (or 2.1) and screen turns to black (or `Activity` pause) for seconds. As [doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#instant-run) explained first build may take longer in `A.S 2.0` But this issue happen in Runtime.

A quick fix based on @Skadoosh comment's would be disable **instant Run**:

```
Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run
```

**More info:**

> When you deploy a clean build, Android Studio instruments your app to
>   allow Instant Run to push code and resource updates. Although updating
>   the running app happens much more quickly, **the first build may take
>   longer to complete**. You can improve the build process by configuring a few DexOptions settings:

```
android {
  ...
  dexOptions {
    maxProcessCount 4 // this is the default value
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
  }
}
```

Also for warning *Before Android 4.1.* it says :

> Instant Run is supported only when you deploy the debug build variant,
>   use Android Plugin for **Gradle version 2.0.0 or higher**, and set
>   **minSdkVersion to 15 or higher** in your app's module-level build.gradle
>   file. For the **best performance, set minSdkVersion to 21 or higher**.

Seeing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StqAZ1OQbqA) video from Googler may help you understand a bit about Instant Run.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, when update Andoid gradle plugin 2.4 to 2.10 & I solved it's by using below instruction

Go to Android studio File->Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck all CheckBox

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem,
use low version gradle can be solved.

*build.gradle*: 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

*gradle-wrapper.properties*: 
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip

Comment: Bad advice. A compilation time is back long, also an instant run must be disabled in settings. Also a size of application is again big.

Answer (score 0):

no need to disable instant run ,but follow my step ,use gradle plugin v2.3.2 and use gradle v3.5 can solve it , enjoy , anyway I solve the problem on my project.