# Emulator disconnect frequently and Android Studio Stuck. How To fix it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have a strange problem which cannot find any fix for it.
Every thing is OK for the first time when i open emulator and AVD run normally. but after 5-10 minutes, the emulator disconnect,it lose it's internet connection and i cant connect to it,also the Android Studio completely stuck and nothing happen !
I should close the emulator and after that everything become normal again.

These are what I tested :

`adb kill-server` and then
`adb start-server`

I also tried connecting and disconnecting again

`adb connect localhost:5554` and also `adb connect emualtor-5554` but still no result.

The worse part is that I can't use Android Studio anymore, even clicking on lines of codes don't work!

Every time I should close the emulator and open it again.

> NOTE : I can't use Genymotion, and I don't want to use my device for debugging!

Can any body have any fix for this damn bug. it made me crazy ...
thanks in advance

EDIT :

The problem is not something related to emulator. Today I try to debug with WiFi connection. Everything was good for a while till the problem happened again with my real device. In log it said :

> deviceXXXXX disconnected

So the problem is with my ADB connection !

What I tested was adding port 5555 to firewall also added ADB to pass through firewall. But still the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your android studio version, jdk version, os?

What api are you targeting?

Can be a problem with new feature of android studio 2 [instant run](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#instant-run).

First try would be turn in off.

Be aware if you are targeting N Developer Preview is required [to use Java 8](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run).

More radical way is to rollback to android studio 1.5 and test.

Comment: android studio version 2.1
jdk 1.8
targeting api 22
i will try turning instant run off and inform you again. @Maxim G

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was with my instant run. As i turned it off, the problem gone.

Comment: I have the same issue but disabling instant run doesn't seem to fix it. Can you specify how you disabled it. Maybr I am doing something wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do these :
Wipe user data (emulator)

(install zlib.i686) execute these command,this is common gradle problem and known for crash/freeze of AS

Comment: On terminal of your emulator

Comment: i tried both adb shell instal zlib.i686
and adb emu instal zlib.i686 from my CMD but nothings happen
. you mean i install a terminall on my emulator ? @cyborg91
by the way i'm using windows server 2012R2

Comment: Adb command should have done the trick....could you use genymotion instead.... Just a suggestion

Comment: no unfortunately, it couldn't connect to VM although i done everything required. The problem exist when i use Wifi debugging too. so there is no assurance that i won't have such a problem with the Genymotion! Thanks a lot for your time @cyborg91