# Android Studio taking too long to build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

**Android Studio**

I am using Stable version Android Studio 2.1. But it is taking very long to build. Currently I have used gradle 2.10 and that too a local version of it. I am using gradle plugin 2.0.0 right now and using jdk 1.8 along with all the options required for Instant run enabled on Studio settings. I even tried with offline options and tried using gradle wrapper also.

My studio is taking very much time to build more than half a hour many a times. Can some body help me out in speeding it up. Am I missing something or using a wrong gradle plugin for Studio 2.1.

Comment: The initial build takes more time than the successive builds. How much is your RAM?

Comment: What is the RAM of your computer?

Comment: Are you using many dependencies libraries in the build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes, I'm also facing the same problem when I upgraded from 1.5 to 2.0

Comment: System Ram is 8gb. I am using Windows 7 OS. Yes there are some dependencies, but before upgrading studio and gradle it was not taking more than 5 minutes to build.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623917/first-launch-take-long-time-in-android-studio-2-0-gradle-2-0

Comment: You can improve your build time with SSD drive too. Also make sure you have access to developer.android.com

Comment: I used jdk1.8, Android Studio 2.1 stabel version with gradle 2.10 & gradle plugin 2.1.0   Also I did added params within gradle.properties:                1. org.gradle.daemon=true                                                                        2. org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5120m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8                3. org.gradle.parallel=true                                                                          4. org.gradle.configureondemand=true

Comment: Don't want to add to the clamour but I'm in the same boat. Builds slowed down to a crawl. Maxing out a quad core box with 8gb of ram I've upgraded to 2.1.1 and it makes no difference!

Comment: 16GB RAM. It got really really slow since 2.1.x