# Android Studio (2.1) does not update app

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.1

When I hit the Run or Debug button, everything appears to be normal. The app starts, breakpoints break...  However, **sometimes** the code does not reflect changes.  The only way to remedy this is restarting AS.  It would be fine if I just needed to restart AS a few times per day.  Unfortunately, this happens as frequently as once every half an hour or so. The target device is an Android 5.1.

How do I know the code is not updated? I just add a statement as following to see if the Android Monitor shows it:

```
Log.d("debug", "********************** THIS IS A NEW LINE OF CODE *********************************");
```

Is there a better way than restarting AS to remedy this?  Or even better, any way to prevent this?

Comment: I think instant run is enable. to have advantage from instant run your min api should be above 15 (for better performance should be above 21)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#instant-run

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. The device is Android 5.1.1

Comment: Whats your min-sdk ? It's seems instant run is buggy now. to prevent this issue you can disable your instant run.

Comment: Also take look at my question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623917/first-launch-take-long-time-in-android-studio-2-0-gradle-2-0

Comment: The miin-sdk is 10. Again, I am testing this right now exclusively with and API 22 device.  I will try disabling instant-run.

Comment: update min-sdk to 15 (or 21) and this issue will be fixed.

Comment: The app needs to support devices with lower API such as 10

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved following this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312900/android-studio-not-deploying-changes-to-app