# Blank screen before splash screen in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I checkout code from svn and I resolved the run time issues and run the application. Then for me blank screen is coming for every first launch the app and for others it's not happening.

I added below line to fix runtime error

```
aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: disable instant run then re run you app.

Comment: refere this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38408079/5955362

Comment: I tried instant run but still facing the same issue. And my Min SDK is 14

Comment: have you tried after disable instant run.?

Comment: yes Patel, I tried the but same issue is coming again.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following theme in your styles.xml and apply it for the splash Activity

```
<style name="AppTranslucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: But my SplashActivity is extending  FragmentActivity and I have to use the same one. Becasue customer is not accepting to change the AppcompatAcitivity.

Comment: FragmentActivity is the parent class of AppCompatActivity so there is no problem in using both. Were you able to run your app with the above theme.?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your style.xml,

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>

</style>
```

In manifest file, call this style.xml as android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" within your Splash screen activity

It will solve your problem.

Comment: But my SplashActivity is extending  FragmentActivity and I have to use the same one. Becasue customer is not accepting to change the AppcompatAcitivity.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.. Add the NoTitleBar theme to you Splash**

```
   <activity

        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    / >
```