# Android white preview screen take diff time based on where the app is starting from

Tags: android, performance

There are two scenarios

1. I run my Android App(fresh install) through Android Studio 2.2.2 and the default android preview screen(white screen) before the my app's splash screen stays close to 10-15 seconds. And this happens only the first time(fresh install) the app is run on any device.
2. I install same .apk (fresh install) through linux terminal using the command

   /app/build/outputs/apk$ adb install -r app-debug.apk

and the click the app icon to launch the app and it shows the preview screen for less then 1 second.

So my question are 1- Why the time difference between these two modes of building and running the app and 2 - What will be the scenarios when I upload my app on play store and a user downloads it from there and tries to run it

Comment: What is the time you have added in the splash Screen?

Comment: there is no time on splash screen, but that's not the issue as Splash doesn't take more then 3 seconds to load. it's the default android preview screen run by Android OS that's taking 15 seconds first time the app is launched from Android Studio

Comment: Found out that instant run in Android Studio 2.0 causes the preview screen to load for long time when fresh install happens. Here is the correct answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623917/first-launch-take-long-time-in-android-studio-2-0-gradle-2-0

Answer (score 0):

So I found out why my app was taking so long while running from android studio 2.2.2. It's because of instant run feature. Please refer below links for more detailed explanation.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407916/android-app-first-start-is-very-slow-and-systrace-shows-30-seconds-of-bindapplic) and [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623917/first-launch-take-long-time-in-android-studio-2-0-gradle-2-0)