# My Android app launches too slow (about 10 secs)

Tags: android, android-activity

When you first launch the app opens `LoginActivity`, next times you launch it opens `MainActivity`. `LoginActivity` only need to remember the username, etc. Everything else is in `MainActivity`.

So `LoginActivity` launches too slow. Please help to optimize the application to launch it faster.

It's my `LoginActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    notFirstInit();

    spinner = (AppCompatSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = editText.getText().toString();
            group = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            saveUserData();

            startMainActivity();
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void saveUserData() {
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("name", name);
    editor.putString("group", group);
    editor.apply();
}

private void notFirstInit() {
    settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (settings.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)) {
        startMainActivity();
        finish();
    } else {
        editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
        editor.apply();
    }
}

private void startMainActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

You can see how much time it takes to launch in logcat:

```
08-13 00:07:12.500 6996-6996/uz.triplet.tuitguide W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/uz.triplet.tuitguide-1/lib/arm
08-13 00:07:21.927 6996-6996/uz.triplet.tuitguide W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/uz.triplet.tuitguide-1/lib/arm
08-13 00:07:21.929 6996-6996/uz.triplet.tuitguide I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package common
08-13 00:07:21.930 6996-6996/uz.triplet.tuitguide I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package com.chummy.jezebel.material.dark.regression
08-13 00:07:22.295 6996-7370/uz.triplet.tuitguide D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false

                                                                    [ 08-13 00:07:22.310  6996: 6996 D/         ]
                                                                    GPU monitor inactive - could not find libgpumonitor.so [(null)] or not enabled (debug.egl.hw.gpumonitor = 0)
08-13 00:07:22.359 6996-7370/uz.triplet.tuitguide D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_vc4.so
08-13 00:07:22.407 6996-7370/uz.triplet.tuitguide I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-13 00:07:22.410 6996-7370/uz.triplet.tuitguide W/egl_server: Allocating storage 1x1 surface type 0x1
08-13 00:07:22.421 6996-7370/uz.triplet.tuitguide W/khrn_client: init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1
08-13 00:07:22.422 6996-7370/uz.triplet.tuitguide W/khrn_client: init_window window 0x43747af8, 480x800 hintTransform 0x0 do_pre 1
```

UPD: I don't know why but when I'm building new APK using `Build` -> `Build APK` application opens instantly. What is the problem with running app clicking the button `Run`

Comment: Are you using emulator? Maybe the problem is not in your app but in the emulator. Try intel x86 instead of arm. If you run it on a smartphone, does it continue to be slow?

Comment: I'm using smartphone (Samsung Galaxy S2 Plus). MainActivity opens fast even second time I launch the app, when starts LoginActivity checks for preferences and lunches MainActivity.

Comment: Which gradle version you are using?

Comment: disable instance run may fix the issue! see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623917/first-launch-take-long-time-in-android-studio-2-0-gradle-2-0

Answer (score 0):

you can use a AsyncTask to launch heavy tasks of your MainActivity , like this :

```
public void StartProgress() {
    new AsyncProgressBar().execute();
}



private class AsyncProgressBar extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {




    protected ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("loading...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //duration of progressbar
        SystemClock.sleep(5000);

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void useless) {
       //your task


        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in this. In the first Activity there is no such tasks, which requires 10 seconds to run.