# Android app crashing while loading image

Tags: android, image

I am trying to load around 168kb (after optimization in tinypng.com) image as splash screen. Its crashing with below VERBOSE (no errors)-

```
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

This is how I have implemented splash screen-

**Activity**:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash1);--> Note this is commented

        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity1.this,MainActivity.class);
                SplashActivity1.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashActivity1.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
```

**Manifest Entry**:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.SplashActivity1"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme= "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.SplashActivity1">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Styles:**

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorTheme</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorBlack</item>
        </style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
                <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.SplashActivity1" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash1</item>
            </style>
```

**Drawable**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/bootpage">

</bitmap>
```

- Running on: Android Emulator API 6

  Thanks in Advance

Comment: .https://stackoverflow.com/a/37512413/3395198

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here .
1 - if you want your activity to be created without a layout (you have commented setContentView()) then you must use `Theme.NoDispaly` .
in your manifest :

```
<activity  android:name = "MyActivity" 
          android:label = "@string/app_name" 
          android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
```

2 - why you would call an activity without a ui ?
for splash pages the standard way is to to declare all your ccomponents and your drawables in xml like anyother activity.
i think there is no need not to use a layout in splash.